# How do modify sp.ui.blogs.js JsLink in Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jslink

I am trying to modify the `sp.ui.blogs.js` JSlink using SharePoint online, but I cannot find this.js anywhere in SharePoint designer. Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify sp.ui.blogs.js on sharepoint online, rather you should override functions defined sp.ui.blogs.js in your custom js file and make sure that your custom js file will be loaded after sp.ui.blogs.js

Comment: Thank you! Where would I add the additional jslink designation in this syntax?

Comment: <FieldRef Name="Permalink"/><FieldRef Name="EmailPostLink"/><FieldRef Name="NumCommentsWithLink"/><FieldRef Name="PublishedDate"/><FieldRef Name="PostCategory"/><FieldRef Name="LikesCount"/><FieldRef Name="LikedBy" Explicit="TRUE"/></ViewFields><RowLimit Paged="TRUE">10</RowLimit><JSLink>sp.ui.blogs.js</JSLink><XslLink>blog.xsl</XslLink><Toolbar Type="None"/></View>